# If ReactJS is for the "View", what is for the rest of the application?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, reactjs, view, single-page-application

Just beginning to look into ReactJS and I see everywhere that you can think about ReactJS as the "View" portion of the application. OK, so if I'm currently using a framework like AngularJS or Kendo UI or Backbone or whatever and I want to use ReactJS as "the View" instead, does it just work out of the box with these other frameworks?

If not, what are people doing about the rest (routing, templating, etc)? Back to plain JS? jQuery? Adding JS libraries piecemeal to cover the other typical application needs? And what about widgets (grids and things that might be better left to add instead of re-inventing the wheel) - are there widget libraries for ReactJS?

Not being cynical - I really am interested. There's certainly enough buzz out there for ReactJS, but I'm just looking for a complete picture of what building a non-trivial application with ReactJS might look like.

Comment: React is a library not a framework, and you will use it to render your views, as you say. You can certainly write your own architecture to run it in plain js, however there are a bunch of architecture frameworks stemming of facebook's flux. I currently use redux and like it a lot, but there are many of them, some may suit your needs better. You should probably start checking out the architecture running behind react before you worry about grids and stuff.

Comment: This question is really too broad for SO, googling will get you plenty info to form your own opinion. but to point you in a general direction: No 2 frameworks work "out of the box" with each other, always best is side-by-side, and not mix. Yes, there are react-friendly solutions out there for routing, templating etc. Including widget libraries. For a complete picture of building non-trivial application, check out [official react pages](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conferences.html).

Comment: Pure suggestions: Use Axios for HTTP calls. Redux for state management. React-Router for routing. Etc, etc. All "certified" libs are here: https://github.com/reactjs

Comment: Instead of putting together the libraries (like the ones @lux is suggesting) peacemeal, search for a react starter kit, where someone else has put together a bunch of good packages that will give you more of a full framework setup, sort of like what you get with Angular.  The great thing about these starter kits is they also come with good build setup and conventions to follow to build a good React application.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone. All great suggestions/advice. This was the info I was looking for to get me going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dislike when people call React the "V in MVC".  It's an oversimplification and leads to confusion.

React isn't part of MVC at all.  It's a fundamental rethinking of design patterns that *replaces* MVC.  That said, because MVC architecture is the gold standard at present, it comes with the understanding that you're going to need to intermix React with MVC tools.

So perhaps a better way of saying things;  In your pre-existing MVC stack, React replaces the V with a new design pattern.  And this new design pattern abstracts certain elements that you might traditionally think of as aspects of the M or C in your stack.

So in terms of how to combine React with your other mvc tools?  It does "work" out of the box, but where you choose to draw the line between traditional MVC and the React design principles is an architecture decision you need to make.

If you're hoping for more of a "Standard" methodology, though, I would suggest familiarizing yourself with the Flux pattern.  There are plenty of implementations of Flux out there, but the basic purpose of the pattern is to handle input/output of data to your React structure.  Most guides will explain it in terms of API calls to your server, but you can easily use the same pattern to talk with other frontend frameworks as well.

Comment: I see what you're saying. And that helps. Thanks. But I'm also looking for what people are using with ReactJS in real projects. You say "design pattern that replaces MVC". So let me ask like this: Patterns aside,  if a team decided to build a really large project with ReactJS, is ReactJS alone all they would use? Earlier comments mention other solutions on GitHub to compliment ReactJS. However, teams building really large (expensive) projects look for solutions from well established sources/companies (stability, maturity, support, bug-fix ratio, etc) before committing.

Comment: All depends on the project.  At the very least, you're going to need a server-side framework to deliver the React elements, and likely setup an API through that as well.  But beyond that, the only boilerplate element that is usually included is some implementation of Flux.  Otherwise it entirely depends on the specific problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

For the rest of the application - vanilla JavaScript, really! Take a look for example, how to implement routing in a ReactJS app with under 100 lines of code:

https://github.com/koistya/demos/tree/master/functional-react-routes
https://github.com/koistya/demos/tree/master/declarative-react-routes